# puppeteer click element inside element

Tags: javascript, node.js, chromium, puppeteer

I'm scraping multiple divs from website and then filtering them, when div is matching my criteria - I want to click an button inside it.

There is my code:

```
const matchelems = async (elements, text) => {
  try {

    var matchings = []

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      let valueHandle = await elements[i].getProperty('innerText');
      let linkText = await valueHandle.jsonValue();

      if (linkText.indexOf(text) > -1) {
        matchings.push(elements[i])
      }

    }
    return matchings

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}

    const elements = await page.$$(`div.foo`)
    const filtered = await matchelems(elements, 'Find that')

    console.log(`Filtered elements: ${filtered.length}`)

    // now click the button in first div

    const nestedButton = await filtered[0].$(`button.submit`);
    console.log(nestedButton)
    console.log(typeof(nestedButton))
    await nestedButton.click()
```

And console output:

```
Filtered elements: 335
null
object
TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
    at dotask (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\app\runtask.js:62:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
```

Comment: it seems that is not working "filtered[0].$(`button.submit`)", do you have the output from this "filtered[0]" ?

Comment: Yes, there is an huge object

Comment: maybe you can try this to see if it's finding the correct elements `let result = await page.evaluate(() => {  return document.querySelectorAll("div.foo button.submit") }); console.log(result)

Comment: I believe the source of your error is probably your CSS selector. What are you trying to select with `button.submit`?

Comment: @AnasTiour button with 'submit' class